# What should I enter for the return value?

Tags: oop, visual-c++

The code below is the protected part of a derived class. The project I was trying to implement is to make food by using two entered ingredients.

I have a lot of concerns about what to get as return value for now.

For reference, we have already declared a virtual destructor.

Personally, I don't want to get a return a value at all, but I get an error message.

What should I do?

```
protected:
string ing(string a, string b)
{
    if (a == name[0] && b == name[1])
        cout << names[0] << endl;
    else if (a == name[0] && b == name[2])
        cout << names[1] << endl;
    else if (a == name[0] && b == name[3])
        cout << names[2] << endl;
    else if (a == name[0] && b == name[4])
        cout << names[3] << endl;
    else if (a == name[0] && b == name[5])
        cout << names[4] << endl;
    else if (a == name[1] && b == name[2])
        cout << names[5] << endl;
    else if (a == name[1] && b == name[3])
        cout << names[6] << endl;
    else if (a == name[1] && b == name[4])
        cout << names[7] << endl;
    else if (a == name[1] && b == name[5])
        cout << names[8] << endl;
    else if (a == name[2] && b == name[3])
        cout << names[9] << endl;
    else if (a == name[2] && b == name[4])
        cout << names[10] << endl;
    else if (a == name[2] && b == name[5])
        cout << names[11] << endl;
    else if (a == name[3] && b == name[4])
        cout << names[12] << endl;
    else if (a == name[3] && b == name[5])
        cout << names[13] << endl;
    else if (a == name[4] && b == name[5])
        cout << names[14] << endl;
    else
        return{};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to return anything, declare your function `void`.

If you have to return an `std::string` (empty?), then `return "";`